# Service Intent Service or Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

My solutions should send a http request and process it's response on every location update. Also it should survive after starting app is killed. I am struggling to pick one of the following designs for this task:

1. Create a location broadcast listener on a Service.
2. Crete an Intent Service which would listen to location update intents.
3. Create a receiver which would listen to location update intents.
4. Something else that I haven't mentioned.

Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go like this:

1. create an unbound [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) registered as [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)
2. create an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which receives as context the updated location and send an http request. When the related response is received the intent service sends and intent with the data to be processed;
3. create a broadcast receiver catching the intents sent by the intentService and performing the desired processing on the received data;
4. in the unbound services, whenever a location update occurs, start the intent service. The OS will enqueue each tasks and serve it when possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: why did you choose unbound service rather than broadcast receiver in the first point?